# SQLite Delete Cascade not working

Tags: android, sqlite, cascading-deletes

In Android 4.2, using SQLite 3.7.11, when I delete a row from the Quizzes table, who's schema is below, the corresponding rows in the QuizQuestions table are not deleted.

I can't figure out what's wrong. I have tried putting

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
```

before and after the create table statements.

Create table statements:

```
CREATE TABLE quizzes(quiz_name TEXT PRIMARY KEY COLLATE NOCASE);

CREATE TABLE quizQuestions(quiz_name TEXT, question_id INTEGER,
     PRIMARY KEY(quiz_name, question_id),
     FOREIGN KEY(quiz_name) REFERENCES quizzes(quiz_name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
     FOREIGN KEY(question_id) REFERENCES questions(question_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Comment: Is there any error message? other than you noticing it's not working...

Comment: No, nothing shows in LogCat.

Comment: Perhaps it's due to the fact that your primary key is a compound key....

Something like this perhaps.: 






PRIMARY KEY (quiz_name, question_id) ON CONFLICT IGNORE,
CONSTRAINT "PrimaryKey" FOREIGN KEY ("quiz_name", "question_id") REFERENCES "quizQuestions" ("quiz_name", "question_id") ON DELETE CASCADE);

Comment: Check this [post out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371371/how-to-set-cascade-on-sqlite-database-with-compound-primary-foreign-key) will help you greately.

Comment: For me, it failed because the table was already created without the CASCADE statement, so clear the app data and create the table again. It worked for me

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Your database should delete rows from `quizQuestions` in case someone is deleting from `quizzes` or from `questions`. It will ignore the *entire* foreign key constraint in case foreign key support is turned off and you have just regular columns that can contain any value.

SQLite defaults to `PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF` every time you *open* the database. It's not a property of a table or of the schema.

In case you use `SQLiteOpenHelper` put it in `onOpen`. That is the place that is called every time the database is opened. `onCreate` only once when the database is created.

---

What `SQLiteOpenHelper` calls when you call `getWriteableDatabase` for the first time is

1. `onConfigure` every time, API Level >= 16 required
2. depending on the existence and version of the database file the following is called within an transaction

   - `onCreate` if there is no database file. Typically, this happens only once in the entire lifetime of the app.
   - `onUpgrade` if the database version (`PRAGMA user_version` - saved inside the database file) is less then the version supplied in SQLiteOpenHelper's constructor. Happens every time you bump the version in your code.
   - Nothing if file exists and version matches.
3. `onOpen` every time

If the same instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` already has an open database it will just return it and nothing of above happens.

Answer (score 40):

Try adding this right after opening database in your Android app:

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
```

This turns on support for foreign keys, which is necessary for `ON DELETE CASCADE` to work properly.

Comment: Yes, I am doing that but it still doesn't delete.
<br/>
For example,
`db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO quizzes (quiz_name) VALUES('Test1')", null);`
<br/>
`db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO questions (question) VALUES('Question1')", null);`
<br/>
`db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO quizQuestions (quiz_name, question_id) VALUES('Test1', 1)", null);`
<br/>
`db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM quizzes WHERE quiz_name = 'Test1'", null);`
<br/>
leaves the Test1 row in the quizQuestions table.

Comment: It seems like starting from API 16 (which is what you've got) you should do it in onConfigure() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onConfigure%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29

Comment: And use [`db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled%28boolean%29) - but big difference is: `onConfigure` happens before `onCreate`/`onUpdate` so you have constraints enabled there already. E.g. dropping a table will trigger cascading deletes which is maybe not what you intended.

Answer (score 13):

Sqlite disable foreign key constrain by default, so you need to enable it by **simply override onOpen method in your DBhelper class like below**

```
public class YourOwnDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db){
        super.onOpen(db);
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue on visual basic!!! you have to write the command text like this:

> cone.CommandText = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; DELETE FROM employees
>   WHERE cod_emp=0;"

and you have to do it everytime you delete something