# Should I enable foreign key constraint in onOpen or onConfigure

Tags: android, sqlite

I came across different code snippet, regarding enable foreign key constraint in `SQLiteHelper`. I was wondering, should I enable foreign key constraint in `onOpen` or `onConfigure`, if I want to support API < 16 as well.

This discussion suggest `onOpen` is the right place, before API 16 : [Foreign key constraints in Android using SQLite? on Delete cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545558/foreign-key-constraints-in-android-using-sqlite-on-delete-cascade?rq=1)

However, since API 16, official document does mention `onConfigure` is the right place.

```
public void setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled (boolean enable)
...
A good time to call this method is right after calling openOrCreateDatabase(File, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory) or in the onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase) callback.
```

May I know what is the single entry point, for both API 16 and <16 ?

```
@Override 
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    super.onOpen(database);
    if (!database.isReadOnly()) {
        // Enable foreign key constraints 
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    } 
}
```

or

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641250/sqlite-delete-cascade-not-working
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        database.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    } else {
        database.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`onConfigure()` would be ideal but it is only called on API 16 and up. If your `minSdkVersion` is 16 or above, use it.

`onOpen()` has the problem that it is only called after possible `onCreate()`/`onUpgrade()` etc. If you have SQL in `onCreate()`/`onUpgrade()` that requires foreign keys to be enforced, it's too late to set the foreign keys pragma in `onOpen()`. For `minSdkVersion < 16`, consider the following:

- Always enable foreign keys in `onOpen()`.
- If your `onCreate()`/`onUpgrade()` requires foreign keys to be enforced, enable them there, too. There's no harm really enabling them possibly twice.